# how to reach to table content which is coming from ajax in codeception?

Tags: codeception

I want to click the button which is in table,And table is coming from jquery ajax.

I have tried 
`$vic->click("Approved",Locator::href("//*[@id='users']/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a='Approved'"));`

Link or Button by name or CSS or XPath element with 'Approved' was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using module which does not execute client side Javascript code.
If you want to test that code, you must use [WebDriver](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver) module which tests websites using real browser.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i am going to start learning web driver

Answer (score 0):

Like @Naktibalda said, you should look at the [WebDriver](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver) docs. You can do something like this:

```
$I->waitForElement(['id' => 'myButtonFromTheAjaxCall']);
$I->click(['id' => 'myButtonFromTheAjaxCall']);
```

Also, I would use a unique ID on that button coming over from your `AJAX` call if you can rather than using `XPath`, it's quicker I think.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i am going to start learning web driver